# Powershell script how to handle parameters that are directly passed to a module

Tags: powershell

I am creating a wrapper and in my `ps1` file I want to invoke:

`ConnectTo-PSSession -Path "test" -Confirm`

Since I want to wrap this call I've created a ps1 file with those same params:

```
Param(
  [string]$Path,
  [switch]Confirm
)
```

Now I would like to call the ConnectTo-PSSession with those parameters but the main problem is that I dont want to even call the flag if its not required:

`ConnectTo-PSSession -Path $Path $Confirm //Confirm here is not working`

I took a look at `Invoke-Expression` but it seems like it will have security issues. Is there a way for me to achieve my result without `Invoke-Expression`? I can of course start writing `If` statements but this does not scale well with multiple parameters since I will need a insane amount of those checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

you can provide a default value in the param block:

```
Param(
  [string]$Path = $PWD ,
  [switch]$Confirm = $True
)
```

The Switch parameter won't accept the value of `$Confirm` without especialy beeing called. To calle the switch parameter use `... -Confirm:$Confirm` without a space after `:`

Comment: Why would you give a switch parameter a default value of $True, where it already has a default value of $False when not present in the call?

Comment: @Theo Depends on how you implement it. I have seen a lot of switch parameters, that do the opposite of what their name would suggest. Others are inversed like `-NoConfirmation` or something like that. In one of my scripts I calculate the value of a switch based uppon if another parameter is filled: `[switch]$useGUI = $([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($CsvPath))` > Switch is `$true` if no `CsvPath` is provided. in that case I show a GUI. Otherwise the script is pure commandline. But I can force it to show GUI and provide the path, too!

Comment: But then I suggest you define it as `[bool]` and not use `[switch]` contrary to what it is designed for..

Answer (score 2):

Since you have made `Confirm` as switch parameter (but forgot to prefix it with a dollar sign), change the script like this:

```
Param(
  [string]$Path,
  [switch]$Confirm
)
ConnectTo-PSSession -Path $Path -Confirm:$Confirm
```

Now, if you invoke that script ***with*** the `-Confirm` switch, it will be interpreted as $true, whereas when you leave the swith off, `ConnectTo-PSSession` with Confirm being interpreted as $false